# Why is syslogd and klogd missing messages?

Tags: linux-kernel, syslog

I'm running kernel 2.6.37 on an ARM machine.

I started `syslogd` and `klogd` with:

```
klogd -c 7
syslogd -l 7
```

But only a small portion of `printk()` messages are logged to `/var/log/messages` compared with what I see in `dmesg`.

Am I missing something here?

Are there other ways to log kernel messages to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Please check /etc/syslog.conf file for a proper settings. Enabling  debug level 7 on syslogd doesn't guarantee all the log messages would be logged on to /var/log/messages. The file /etc/syslog.conf has the instructions on where to log these messages. The messages can be logged on to a local file , sent to a remote syslog server, displayed on local console based on sysogd.conf configuration. If you need all the log messages to be logged on to /var/log/messages file ensure you have the following line in /etc/syslog.conf

```
*.*     /var/log/messages
```

Comment: `/etc/syslog.conf` doesn't exist on my system. I created the file but no luck. Also I prefer not to log messages by default, because after kernel crashes and reboots, useful messages from before the crash will be over written.